# <span> html duplicate print out

Tags: javascript, html

i am new with using span . i am trying to print out information that i get from javascript script twice on same page.

i can print the information that i get once but when i decide to print the information second time it doesn't display it

**This one works**

```
    <div id="layer4" class="auto-style10" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 427px; z-index: 2; left: 1020px; top: 90px">
    <span class="auto-style8"><h4>Incident Details</h4><br />
        </span>
    <br />

&nbsp;<h6> Report ID : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="ReportID"></span> <br />

&nbsp;<h6> Description : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="Description"></span><br />

&nbsp;<h6> Category : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="Category"></span>  <br/>   

&nbsp;<h6> Date and Time : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="DateTime"></span> <br />

&nbsp;<h6> User Id/ Mobile Number : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="UserID"></span><br />
    <br />


<span id="ReportID"></span> 
    <form method="post" action="http://www.al-qarra.com/police_new/map2/changelevel.php" >

<select name="SelectCat" style="position: absolute; width: 60px; z-index: 2;">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<input name="reportno" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['incidentid']; ?>">

<input name="ChangeCat" id="SelectCat" type="submit" value="Change Status" style="position: absolute; left: 100px; width: 110px; z-index: 2;"/>

        </form>

</div>
```

**But when i copy the same div on to the same page but different location it does not display the information**

```
    <div id="layer44" class="auto-style10" style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 427px; z-index: 2; left: 1020px; top: 300px">
    <span class="auto-style8"><h4>Incident Details</h4><br />
        </span>
    <br />

&nbsp;<h6> Report ID : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="ReportID"></span> <br />

&nbsp;<h6> Description : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="Description"></span><br />

&nbsp;<h6> Category : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="Category"></span>  <br/>   

&nbsp;<h6> Date and Time : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="DateTime"></span> <br />

&nbsp;<h6> User Id/ Mobile Number : </h6> &nbsp; <span id="UserID"></span><br />
    <br />

</div>
```

**This is my javascript as requested**

```
</style>
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>

            $("#ReportID").text(nreportid);
            $("#Description").text(ndesc);
            $("#Category").text(ncat);

    }
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've spotted several issues so far:

- You've got duplicate id's, which isn't allowed.
- You *think* you're adding that you're adding those elements somewhere else, but you're positioning them *absolutely*, so they're bound to overlap
- You're leaving the `<span>` elements empty, yet add `&nbsp;` in between the tags... does look like you've got tag-soup in the making
- The first code has a form at the end, the second doesn't. Seeing as they overlap, they the second bunch of nodes might remain tucked away for ever.
- Your JavaScript code contains two (*huuuge*) functions, that aren't being called AFAIK. This might come across as rude/arrogant but *please, tidy up your code* as suggested [in the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)
- You're messing with the `z-index`, why?

But none of these guesses come even close to being conclusive so long as you're not showing us your JavaScript code. If you're using `document.write('your-html');`, for example, we can just tell you that that's your problem and go our ways for evermore... So please [set up a decent fiddle or something](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: so you are saying that i should just replace the names of each element to something else and that will work

Comment: i did try changing each element , still doesn't work. can you please show me example realting to my code :)

Comment: @MuzZaden: Not quite, I'm still saying that all I'm doing here is guessing. You might want to add this to the bottom of your script, too: `$(document).ready(load);` to call the load function when the document is fully loaded. Also keep an eye on your console...

Comment: if its posible can you have look at my other question , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375183/html-span-textbox

Comment: @MuzZaden: I've had a look, and posted an answer there, too

Answer (score 0):

try with removing

```
style="position: absolute; width: 300px; height: 427px; z-index: 2; left: 1020px; top: 300px"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute is required to be unique. If there are going to be multiple items on the page that you need to perform the same action on, use a `class` instead.

Comment: the two id are different, one is id="layer4" and other is id="layer44"

Comment: `<span id="ReportID"></span>` etc are the same in both.

Comment: id="ReportID" is the output that i am getting from javascript, so i cant really change it

Comment: @MuzZaden: Sure you can: `yourHTMLAsTxt = yourHTMLAsTxt.replace(/ReportID/g,'$1_2');` converts all _"ReportID"_ occurances into _"ReportID_2"_. Job done