# How to add span into input text box in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I can print information out from JavaScript, how can I add the information to textbox

the following code displays information relation to `description12` from JavaScript

```
<h6> Description : </h6>  <span id="Description12"> </span><br />
```

I am now trying to get the information into textbox

```
<input name="reportnoss" type="text" id="Description12">
```

which does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can't give two controls on the same page identical IDs - they must be unique.

The ID you give the input text box should be for that control.

You will need to use javascript or jQuery to do this if you must do it client-side.

Something like:

`document.getElementById("reportnoss").innerText=document.getElementById("Description12").innerText;`
would work if you gave the input field the ID `reportnoss`

Answer (score 1):

As other answers say, you can't have same id.

```
<h6> Description : </h6>  <span id="Description12"> </span><br />

<input name="reportnoss" type="text" id="DescriptionTextBox">
```

Javascript to set the span's text to input text:

```
document.getElementById("DescriptionTextBox").value=document.getElementById("Description12").innerText;
```

Note you should use `.value` and **not** `.innerText` for `input type="text"`

If this is not what you were asking for leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot have 2 elements in the same document that have the same `id`. Remove the `input`'s `id` or change it to another `id`.

```
<h6> Description : </h6>  <span id="Description12"> </span><br />
<input name="reportnoss" type="text" id="Input_Description12">
```

Then, to get the text in the textbox and put it into the `span`:

```
var txt = document.querySelector("#Input_Description12").value;  //get the text
document.querySelector("#Description12").innerText = txt;        //put it in

  -and the opposite-

var txt = document.querySelector("#Description12").innerText;
document.querySelector("#Input_Description12").value = txt;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/bFZMb/

Method used:

- [`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector)
- `.innerText`